# How to find if a particular device is registered in a Development Provisioning Profile?

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

I have been trying to find out if my iphone is there on a particular development provisioning profile in the developer's account. With a distribution provisioning profile, you can easily add or find devices, but I am not able to figure out how to do it for a development one.

Comment: why not? ..click on `edit` button below development provisioning profile

Comment: Edit button is disabled for Development profile.